# What is the easy and proper way of communicating components in React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks, data-sharing

After a week of learning React and also diving into React Hooks, I stumbled into the problem of communicating between components like the following:

- parent to child
- child to parent
- child to child (siblings)

I was able to communicate from a child to its own parent by adding a prop with the name onChange and passing by a function that is defined on its parent.

So this is what I had in the **parent**:

```
function handleChange(val: any) {
    console.log(val)
    console.log(hiddenPiece)
}

return ( 
    <div className="board-inner">
        {puzzlePieces}
    </div>
)
```

And this is the **child**:

```
props.onChange(props.index);
```

The question really is, how am I able to communicate from the parent straight with its child after like a click state or when the children's state change? I have been searching for easy samples, but I guess I am not good at my research for now. I need someone who can help me out with clear examples. Thanks for taking the time to help me out here.

Comment: Use one of state management frameworks, e.g: [redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Comment: consider React.Context or redux.js、recoil.js、rematch.js ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic example for the two of cases you described (parent > child & child > parent). The parent holds state, has some functions to modify it and renders two childs.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-browser-y9hdt?file=/src/App.tsx

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(1);

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCounter((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  };

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    setCounter((prevCount) => prevCount - 1);
  };

  // used as prop with the children
  const doubleTheCounter = () => {
    setCounter((prevCount) => prevCount * 2);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent counter</h1>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>-</button>
      <ChildTriple countFromParent={counter} />
      <DoubleForParent doubleCallback={doubleTheCounter} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The first child receives state from the parent and uses that do display *something* different ("triple" in this case):

```
type ChildTripleProps = { countFromParent: number };

// Receives count state as prop
const ChildTriple = ({ countFromParent }: ChildTripleProps) => {
  const [tripleCount, setTripleCount] = useState<number>(countFromParent * 3);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTripleCount(countFromParent * 3);
  }, [countFromParent]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Child triple counter</h1>
      <p>{tripleCount}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The second child receives a callback function from the parent, which changes the state at the parent:

```
type DoubleForParentProps = { doubleCallback: () => void };

// Receives a function as prop, used to change state of the parent
const DoubleForParent = ({ doubleCallback }: DoubleForParentProps) => {
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    doubleCallback();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Child double counter</h1>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Double the parent count</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

For your third case (child <> child) there are a lot of different options. The first one is obviously holding state in their parent and passing that down to both childs, similar to the parent in this example.

If you have grandchildren or components even further apart in the tree it probably makes sense to use some kind of state management solution. Most of the time the built in [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is totally sufficient. If you want to go for best practices regarding context I highly recommend [Kent C. Dodds' blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react). This will also help you get to know the React eco system better.

External state libraries are, in my opionion, either a) [too complex](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) [as a beginner](https://github.com/react-spring/zustand), b) [really new and not battle proven](https://recoiljs.org/) or c) [not a best practice anymore or overblown](https://mobx.js.org/README.html).